# Flash Professional - Looping Specific Animation Sequence Layers Infinitely

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript

I am trying to seamlessly loop specific layers containing .swf or .flv movies infinitely, independent of other layers in the timeline.

I have attempted to use the gotoAndPlay("x"); method, but the target layer always freezes on the last frame for about .5 seconds before executing the gotoAndPlay command. The only situation in which it doesn't freeze is when frame "x" is the first frame of the project.

No other actionscript is being used anywhere else in this project.

Does anybody know of any other method for achieving this type of loop, or a fix for this apparent bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you using videos on those layers? if you are, try increase the amount of keyframes or make all frames a single image, then import them as a sequence.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, as both individual frames (images) and also as movie clips. In the case of movie clips, I've even tried adding additonal (an) keyframe(s) to the end. In all instances, there is still a pause on the last frame.